# MVVM with TreeView - add nodes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, treeview

How to add nodes to the tree (i.e. add new child to a specific node in the tree during runtime) in this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) of TreeView?

Should the new nodes be added to 
(a) the model or to 
(b) the view-model?

How changes to one of them effects the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should be added to the ViewModel, which will add them to the model (to keep consistency between the model and the ViewModel). In the ViewModel, the collection of child nodes should be an `ObservableCollection<T>`, so that the UI is notified when a node is added/removed